# VBA to set pivot filter as single selection

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Resolved my original problem from earlier today - now I have working code that isn't producing quite as polished a result as I'd like.  In a nutshell, I'm looping through all sheets and setting all pivots to be filtered to a single value.  I don't want multiple values unless the filter is cleared and showing everything.  My code below shows the desired *data* but the filter on the pivot itself displays as Multiple Values (with the one value checked). How can I get it to treat this as a single selection, and show that single value on the pivot filter?

```
Sub Loop_Complex_bkup()
Dim wks As Worksheet, strName As String, pvt As PivotTable, strPvtName As String

For Each wks In Worksheets
strName = wks.Name
For Each pvt In wks.PivotTables
    strPvtName = pvt.Name
    With Sheets(strName).PivotTables(strPvtName).PivotFields("OrderSubType")
        .ClearAllFilters
        For Each PivotItem In .PivotItems
            If PivotItem = "Complex" Then PivotItem.Visible = True
            If PivotItem <> "Complex" Then PivotItem.Visible = False
        Next
    End With
Next
Next

Set wks = Nothing
Set pvt = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I had a similar issue I finally resolved, I decided to post the solution(s) I found for anyone still searching. The code I used was:

```
With Sheets(strName).PivotTables(strPvtName).PivotFields("OrderSubType")
    .ClearAllFilters
    .CurrentPage = "Complex"
End With
```

The `.CurrentPage` selects a single filter item and defaults the `.EnableMultiplePageItems = False`

I am also not sure how the filter displays are affected between pivot tables connected through a slicer, so I would recommend that the `EnableMultiplePageItems` be set the same between such tables.

**Note: for anyone with the same problem, except for wanting `.EnableMultiplePageItems = True`**

I had to use the following code to fix the filter display.

```
With Sheets(strName).PivotTables(strPvtName).PivotFields("OrderSubType")
    .ClearAllFilters
    .CurrentPage = "Complex"
    .EnableMultiplePageItems = True

    For Each PI In .PivotItems
        If PI.Name <> "Complex" Then PI.Visible = False
    Next PI
End With
```

I know it looks redundant, but the display wouldn't fix itself until I added the `.CurrentPage` and `.EnableMultiplePageItems` lines.

Answer (score 0):

The command you're looking for is .EnableMultiplePageItems.  If I'm understanding the question correctly, this is what you're looking for:

```
        With Sheets(strName).PivotTables(strPvtName).PivotFields("OrderSubType")
            .ClearAllFilters
            .EnableMultiplePageItems = False
```

Comment: I'd tried that...  it doesn't change my final result. Somehow I think the "for each pivot item" block overrides it, but I haven't found a way to successfully set the pivot filter any other way.

Comment: Have you tried the .EnableMutliplePageItems after the the For loop?

Comment: Yes, same thing.  I get the filtered data but the filter still shows as "(Multiple Items)"

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and the below works:

With Sheets(strName).PivotTables(strPvtName).PivotFields("OrderSubType").CurrentPage=_
"(All)"

With Sheets(strName).PivotTables(strPvtName).PivotFields("OrderSubType")
.ClearAllFilters
.EnableMultiplePageItems = False
.CurrentPage = "Complex"

End With

Comment: You have two With and one End With. Which is the right one? Please fix your answer.